# Run-time check: stack around variable was corrupted

Tags: c++

I am creating a program that rewrites an array with values from a file. I have linked the code below. When running the file I get the error "Run-time check failure, stack around 'arr' variable was corrupted.

Also, the output of the program returns all the array locations with the same number,

`arr[0] = -858993460`

The numbers in the file, separated by a line are:
    `12`
    `13`
    `15`

```
#include<iostream>;
#include<fstream>;
using namespace std;
template <class T>
void init(T * a, int size, T v)//done
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[size] = v;
    }
}

bool getNumbers(char * file, int * a, int & size)//not done
{
    int count = 0;
    ifstream f(file);

    while (f.good() == true && count < 1)
    {
        f >> a[count];
        count++;
    }

    if (size > count)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (size < count)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void testGetNumbers()
{
    int arr[5];
    int size = 5;

    cout << "Testing init and getNumbers." << endl;

    init(arr, 5, -1);

    cout << "Before getNumbers: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "arr[" << i << "] = " << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    if (getNumbers("nums.txt", arr, size))
    {
        cout << size << " numbers read from file" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Array not large enough" << endl;
    }

    cout << "After getNumbers: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "arr[" << i << "] = " << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    testGetNumbers();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I ran your code through `astyle` to fix the formatting. Please post properly formatted code.

Comment: Is there anything else in the message, such as a line number? What compiler and flags are you using?

Comment: FWIW your `init` function already exists, under the name `std::fill_n()`.  It even has the same order of parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the `main` function, the line

```
return 0;
```

... is not necessary because that's the default return value for `main`. I would remove it, some people insist on having it, I think most people don't care. But it's always a good idea to be fully aware of what the code expresses, implicitly or explicitly, so: returning 0 expresses that the program *succeeded*.

For an explicit `main` return value I recommend using the names `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` from the `<stdlib.h>` header.

Then it's much more clear.

---

`main` calls `testGetNumbers`, which, except for an output statement, starts like this:

```
int arr[5];
int size = 5;
init(arr, 5, -1);
```

As it happens the `init` function is has Undefined Behavior *and* doesn't fill the array with `-1` values as intended, but disregard. For now, look only at the verbosity above. Consider writing this instead:

```
vector<int> arr( 5, -1 );
```

Using `std::vector` from the `<vector>` header.

---

Following the call chain down into `init`, one finds

```
a[size] = v;
```

That attempts to assign value `v` to the item just beyond the end of the array.

That has **Undefined Behavior**.

Should probably be

```
a[i] = v;
```

But as noted, this whole function is redundant when you use `std::vector`, as you should unless strictly forbidden by your teacher.

---

Back up in `testGetNumbers` it proceeds to call `getNumbers`, in that function we find

```
ifstream f(file);

while (f.good() == true && count < 1)
{
    f >> a[count];
    count++;
}
```

Generally one should never use `f.good()` or `f.eof()` in a loop condition: use `f.fail()`. Also, ~never compare a boolean to `true` or `false`, just use it directly. Then the loop can look like this:

```
ifstream f(file);

while (!f.fail() && count < 1)
{
    f >> a[count];
    count++;
}
```

Tip: in standard C++ you can write `!` as `not` and `&&` as `and`. With the Visual C++ compiler you have to include the `<iso646.h>` header to do that.

*Disclaimer*: the fixes noted here do not guarantee that the loop is correct *for your intended purpose*. Indeed the increment of `count` also when the input operation fails, looks probably unintended. Ditto for the loop limit.

---

The function continues (or rather, ends) with

```
if (size > count)
{
    return true;
}
else if (size < count)
{
    return false;
}
```

This has a big problem: what if `size == count`? Then the execution continues to fall off the end of the function without returning a value. This is again **Undefined Behavior**.

I leave it to you to decide what you want the function to return in that case, and ensure that it does that.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. 

One more question if you have time. I edited the while loop for "bool getNumbers" to how you suggested, and made the changes to the init function. 

The program now runs without errors, however the "getNumbers" array does not seem to rewrite the array. All the outputs are still shown as -1, after the function has run. If I am not mistaken, the first three locations of the array should output the numbers from the file.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The contextual conversion to `bool` is equivalent to `!f.fail()`. Which is not equivalent to `f.good()`. And it's a good idea to test that the file was opened OK, and correspondingly, an ungood idea to not do that.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Again no, but it's natural to assume that that the OP only *meant* to increment `count` for each successful read, and also to not use `1` as the loop limit. But difficult to advice about that without doing the homework. Sorry for not adding disclaimer (not sure if I even thought about it).

Comment: @BenVoigt: added disclaimer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This line in the first loop looks like having error.

```
a[size] = v;
```

It causes out of array bound access and memory/stack corruption. It should be

```
a[i] = v;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `init` function...

```
template <class T>
void init(T * a, int size, T v)//done
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[size] = v;
    }
}
```

Nope:

```
a[size] = v;
```

Yup:

```
a[i] = v;
```